# mySQL Select ONLY data that contains some letters in any order

Tags: mysql, select

Imagine a table like:

```
string
12345
1234567
13254
123
```

I just want to select those rows that contain: 1,2,3,4,5 in any order. And also those that even being shorter, all the letters in it at least are from that "array".

Selected strings might have ONLY those chars 1,2,3,4,5  in any order, and not of them necesary.

Selected:

```
12345
123
1324
```

Not Selected:

```
123a
1123
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head.....

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn RLIKE '/^([1-5])+$/';
```

Comment: Have you tried it because i have made a table as per his need and checked your querry and its giving null result

Comment: A quick look at the docs, and I see that manual makes no reference to pattern delimitation - try it again without the '/' chars.

Comment: Is there any way to make this Unicode-compatible? The query seems to return garbage when used with Japanese characters.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name RLIKE '^([1-5])+$';
```